# What could cause a Errors$NativeIoException: recvAddress(..) failed: Connection timed out?

Tags: netty

Context: we use Netty to connect to a device, using TCP/Epoll. Connecting is successful and messages are exchanged. At some point we get this exception:

```
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: recvAddress(..) failed: Connection timed out
```

What could cause this exeption? Sure, it says the connection timed out, but that doesn't make sense to me here. Because connection timeout usually results from failure to establish the connection in the first place, but in this case the connection has already been established successfully (and used).

Any ideas as to what could cause this exception?

Comment: Just a quick question: Did you use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to look at the packets? This way you might uncover some useful data. (And it could be of help to get an answer).

Comment: No, we don't have Wireshark on that machine. It's something to consider, though.

Comment: Well, technically windows has a build in packet capture method [howto](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-quietly-got-a-built-in-network-sniffer-how-to-use/) [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/pktmon/pktmon). But converting that format is/was tricky (unsure if wireshark already reads it)